# Node.js , path.js crashes after a lot of users connect to application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path.js

Hi guys I have an application written in Express.js , and Im using socket.io to display realtime data to users.

When there is more then lets say 10 users on the website suddenly node servers crashes and Im getting this error

```
path.js:309 var path = (i >= 0) ? arguments[i] : process.cwd();
```

Even if I'm alone on the website and I refresh page multiple times , or just stay on the website and click on the pages I get the same error , does anyone knows how to fix this ?

EDIT : This is the whole error

```
path.js:309
      var path = (i >= 0) ? arguments[i] : process.cwd();
                                                   ^
Error: EMFILE, too many open files
    at Object.exports.resolve (path.js:309:52)
    at ExpressHandlebars.extend.loadTemplate (/Users/sredoje/Downloads/expressjs-template/node_modules/express3-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:111:25)
    at ExpressHandlebars.load (/Users/sredoje/Downloads/expressjs-template/node_modules/express3-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:153:18)
    at /Users/sredoje/Downloads/expressjs-template/node_modules/express3-handlebars/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:224:13
    at /Users/sredoje/Downloads/expressjs-template/node_modules/express3-handlebars/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:108:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/Users/sredoje/Downloads/expressjs-template/node_modules/express3-handlebars/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
    at async.each (/Users/sredoje/Downloads/expressjs-template/node_modules/express3-handlebars/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:107:9)
    at _asyncMap (/Users/sredoje/Downloads/expressjs-template/node_modules/express3-handlebars/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:223:9)
    at Object.map (/Users/sredoje/Downloads/expressjs-template/node_modules/express3-handlebars/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:201:23)
    at ExpressHandlebars.mapTemplates (/Users/sredoje/Downloads/expressjs-template/node_modules/express3-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:157:19)
    at fn (/Users/sredoje/Downloads/expressjs-template/node_modules/express3-handlebars/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:579:34)
    at Object._onImmediate (/Users/sredoje/Downloads/expressjs-template/node_modules/express3-handlebars/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:495:34)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
>> application exited with code
```

8

Comment: Is that the whole error?

Comment: @Joe I added full error message to post

Comment: How many templates do you have?

Comment: @Joe about 10 is it to much ?

Comment: No, i'm wondering if you're doing something strange that's causing templates to load/reload continuously.  Can  you show any relevant code around where this is throwing?

Comment: I have my templates in views folders , and they are written with handlebars , this is where Im loading them app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); Thats all

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/45

Looks like it's a "too many open files" error, which could happen if your app is interacting with a large amount of files in the filesystem.  You don't indicate what your platform is, I'm assuming Linux, the suggested fix following through the links is to up your ulimit.

The full quoted fix:

> `EMFILE` means there are too many open files. Brunch watches all your project files and it's usually a pretty big number. You can fix this error with setting max opened file count to a bigger number using the command `ulimit -n <number>` (10000 should be enough).

Comment: I already done that and stetted  max files to 2400 , It helped but whats the solution for production , I dont want to my website to crash when there is a lot of users connected ?

Comment: Rewrite your app to access less files? There's not enough information here to provide a real analysis of why you're using so many files and if it's inherently necessary, though it shouldn't be a problem to up your ulimit to 10000 in production. Here's a generic suggestion: if you're maintaining multiple file handles to the same file, one for each user, then you could rewrite it so that it only maintains a single file handle and re-uses it whenever that file needs to be accessed. It's possible that node or linux are intelligent enough to optimize that away, I dunno, but it's worth a look.

Comment: Should uglify with Grunt , to put everything in one file solve this problem ? For example I would have just app.js

Comment: I don't know, again, I don't know how or why you're accessing a bunch of files.  But if it's easy to try, give it a shot, set your ulimit back to 1000 (the default), run your uglified code and see if file inclusions were where you were experiencing the problem.

Comment: one more thing , When i type sudo ulimit -n 10000 and then i type ulimit -a i got open files  (-n) 999